# TCP Load Balancer In Front of TLS/SSL Endpoints

Tags: ssl, networking, load-balancing

Last week I was playing with a load balancer for my TLS-enabled endpoints (share the same certificate) and was surprised it is possible to have TPC load balancer in place in front of SSL endpoint. Having that configured it was possible to communicate with TCP load balancer as like it configured to support TLS/SSL. So, I would like to ensure such a network configuration is fully working solution:

1. TLS/SSL session and handshake workflow are stateless, meaning it is possible to start handshake with a primary server and end it with a mirror. Is it true?
2. Are there any hidden dangers I must be aware of?
3. If previous statements are true, what the reason to to do all TLS/SSL work on a load balancer itself?

P.s. the reason I do not do TLS/SSL work on a load balancer is that I need to balance multiple proprietary endpoint only supports SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TLS/SSL session and handshake workflow are stateless, meaning it is possible to start handshake with a primary server and end it with a mirror. Is it true?

No. I suspect your load balancer is using TCP keep-alive so that the handshake is completing on the same server every time.

> Are there any hidden dangers I must be aware of?

You may be incurring a significant performance penalty. HTTPS has "session keys" that are, probably by default, unique to the server. If you aren't able to do something like sticky sessions with the load balancer, then you will do a full handshake every time a client moves from one server to the other.

You also will have session tickets that won't work between servers, so session resumption will probably not work either, and fall back to a full handshake. Some servers support configuring a common session ticket key, like nginx.

> If previous statements are true, what the reason to to do all TLS/SSL work on a load balancer itself?

Well, they aren't entirely true. There are other benefits though. The main one being that the load balancer can be more intelligent since it can see the plaintext of the session. An example might be examining the request's cookies to determine which server to send the request to. This is a common need for blue/green deployments.